# Html2Canvas doesn't capture google map elements correctly

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, png, jpeg, html2canvas

I'm having a problem when I try to capture google maps using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).
Here's my map:

[image]

The captured screenshot:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
const handleMapExportToPng = (e) => {
    const input = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

    html2canvas(input, {
        useCORS: true,
        allowTaint: false,
    }).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        saveAs(imgData, 'map');
    });
};
```

But if I use `foreignObjectRendering: true` the result becomes this:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the requirement to stick with some client side solution? Maybe try puppeteer for this problem but it'll add network request time.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, Yes I need a client-side solution.

Comment: saving Google Maps as images might be in violation of the Google Maps Terms of Service. Check item 3.2.3 (a)(b): https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#3.-license.

Comment: @ArfizurRahman, were you able to figure out the problem? I am having the same kind of issue.